# Comparing averages of two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, descriptive-statistics

Say I want to check if the averages of 2 groups (A and B) are the same.

For each member in group A, there are some observations; same applies for group B.

If I want to take the average of A and B, I have 2 options:

- take the individual average of each member in A, and then B, and compute the averages of A and B that way
- take the average of the observations in A and B.

However, these 2 methods can produce very different SD's, and that means a very different test statistic.

Say I want to take the SD of group B, I then have 2 choices:

- I look at all the observations of all the members pooled together
- I take the average of every member's observations and then do the SD on those averages of members

Which one makes more sense, if one wants to check if there is a statistically significant difference (assuming a simple z-test is used) between the two averages?

Comment: This is a 'repeated measures' experiment, that term should lead you to plenty of discussion. Naïve pooling (option 1) ignores within-subject correlation (not good), though the fact that the results are apparently *very* different suggests either pretty significant imbalance or asymmetry in your outcomes. e: re-reading you mention it's mostly the SD (SE?) that's different, you should be careful with pseudo-replication here.